# Intellij remote debug mode is too slow

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I am experiencing problems with remote debugging through Intellij 14.

I can connect to web application, which is based on tomcat 8, remotely. However, when I have connected, set only one breakpoint on a particular code line(not method) and run something on website, everything becomes sooo slow.

Why it happens so? What I need to do to improve this situation?

Comment: I'd like to know too. In my case, I think it has to do with the app being deployed on a machine on the other side of the globe.